# Inserir quebra de linha (enter) usando HTML codes

Tags: html

Estou a tentar colocar um enter/quebra de linha (`\n`, `<br />`, etc) num `title` de um elemento html. Para tal, fui pesquisar por HTML Codes algo que fosse equivalente ao `&nbsp` usado para dar um "espaço". Encontrei poucas referencias mas nenhuma que realmente funcionasse...

Encontrei o `&#10` mas não funciona ([fonte](http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-ascii.htm)).

Como posso realmente dar um enter/quebra de linha num `title` de um elemento html?

Código:

```
<input type="button" value="butão" title="tesxto 1 &#160 texto 2"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pymgx0ws/

**Edit:**

Na minha aplicação estou a utilizar devexpress, e não posso usar:

```
<a title='1ª linha
2ª linha
3ª linha
'>link</a>
```

Comment: Isso não seria um [problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1202/6077)?

Comment: Talvez, mas se existe um HTML Code para o espaço, penso que também exista para o enter. Até posso estar enganado, mas se não for por HTML Code penso não dê para dar um enter :)

Comment: @PapaCharlie, não sabes até que ponto faz sentido no meu caso usar ou não uma quebra de linha para separar informação. Vou-te dar o meu exemplo: Tenho uma listagem com 18 colunas, com tantas colunas senti a necessidade de substituir algumas das colunas por icons, e o utilizador ao passar o cursor por cima consegue saber qual a informação da respectiva coluna. Neste caso ao passar o cursor no icon, consegue saber qual o utilizador que criou, ENTER, o utilizador que alterou os dados da linha

Comment: @PapaCharlie, estou a utilizar o tooltip do bootstrap para fazer isso mesmo. Mas o mesmo pede que o texto a apresentar no tooltip seja definido no title

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/21p5swbw/, veja se é isso que você deseja

Comment: Sim, é isso que quero. Só que tenho um problema: Estou a utilizar devexpress e não permite que dê enter's a definir o elemento. E como o &nbsp funciona na perfeição, pensei que existisse um para o enter

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[<sub>**jsfiddle**</sub>](http://jsfiddle.net/d7r2o3aw/)

Use `&#013;` para quebra de linha

```
<a title='1ª linha&#013;2ª linha&#013;3ª linha'>link</a>
```

<sub>**output**</sub>

```
1ª linha
2ª linha
3ª linha
```

[fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14348943)

Comment: Interessante, não sabia dessa. Parabéns, +1.

Comment: Também não sabia, fui procurar como escapar enter para formatar no bootstrap e achei no SO mas esqueci de colocar a fonte... Depois vou procurar o motivo do *tooltip* não aceitar o `<br>` e atualizo se houver informação.

Comment: Não sabia dessa ai não, muito bacana.

Comment: Eu fiz alguns testes e não funcionou.

Comment: @lorduakiti o exemplo do `jsfiddle` não funcionou?